# Physics SDK for Flash with realicstic model

Tags: flash, physics

There are some open SDK for Flash, that could be done. Rotating photos with physics? Examples of such programs BumTop, [ePic](http://www.epicreal.com), Coloris (no physics). The photo on the plane, it can be moved to the real physics?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of popular 3D physics engines for Flash:

http://code.google.com/p/jiglibflash/

http://code.google.com/p/wow-engine/

Then you can choose a 3D engine for rendering. Jiglib has a list of ones it supports.